# Finding The Cause of an Infinite Loop in Prolog

Tags: debugging, loops, prolog, infinite

I'm sorry to be asking a question as dumb as this, but I'm stuck and I'm not sure what's causing the problem. Its the bucket problem where the program is supposed to find a path to filling one bucket with exactly 2 gallons using a 4 gallon bucket and a 3 gallon bucket.

I used trace in Swipl and found that it loops infinitely in the bucket filling and the bucket emptying clauses (the first 4 predicates) The problem is I'm not sure why it is doing this.

Its probably something dumb and something I'm not getting, but if someone could point me in the right direction or smack some sense into me with a load of bricks I would really appreciate it.

Sorry to waste your time.

```
 :-dynamic bucket/4.

 printIt([]).
 printIt([X,Y|Xs]) :-write("bucket("),write(X),write(Y), write(")"), printIt(Xs).

 go(X,Y) :- bucket(0,0,[0,0],X,Y),printIt([X,Y]).

 /*tests if we have been to this state before*/
 memPairs(X,Y,[X,Y|_]).
 memPairs(X,Y, [_,_|Tail]) :- memPairs(X,Y,Tail).

/*Fill the first bucket*/
bucket(X,Y,T,G1,G2) :- X<4,not(memPairs(4,Y,T)),bucket(4,Y,[4,Y|T],G1,G2).
/*fill the second bucket*/
bucket(X,Y,T,G1,G2) :- Y<3,not(memPairs(X,3,T)),bucket(X,3,[X,3|T],G1,G2).
/*if X is full and Y is not, then empty X*/
/* if X+Y is greater than or equal to 4 then fill Y from X*/
bucket(X,Y,T,G1,G2) :- (X+Y) >= 4, X>0, Z is (Y-(4-X)),not(memPairs(4,Z,T)),bucket(4,Z,[4,Z|T],G1,G2).
/*if X+Y is greater than or equal to 3, then fill X from Y*/
bucket(X,Y,T,G1,G2) :- (X+Y) >=3, Z is (X-(3-Y)), Y>0, not(memPairs(Z,3,T)),bucket(Z,3,[Z,3|T],G1,G2).
/* if it is less, then empty Y */
bucket(X,Y,T,G1,G2) :-(X+Y) =< 3,Z is (X + Y), X>0,not(memPairs(Z,0,[T])),bucket(Z,0,[Z,0|T],G1,G2).
/*if it is less than 4, empty X*/
bucket(X,Y,T,G1,G2) :-(X+Y) =< 4, Y>0, Z is (X + Y),not(memPairs(0,Z,[T])),bucket(0,Z,[0,Z|T],G1,G2).
bucket(4,Y,T,G1,G2) :- not(memPairs(0,Y,T)),bucket(0,Y,[0,Y|T],G1,G2).
/*if Y is full and X is not, then empty Y*/
bucket(X,3,T,G1,G2) :-not(memPairs(X,0,T)),bucket(X,0,[X,0|T],G1,G2).

bucket(X,2,T,G1,G2) :- not(memPairs(X,Y,[T])), bucket(2,X,[X,Y|T],G1,G2).
bucket(2,Y,T,G1,G2) :- not(memPairs(2,Y,[T])),G1,G2.
```

as a note the bucket predicate starts off as 0,0 (empty buckets) and attempts to get to (2,0) while it is doing that it checks a list of previous states to make sure it hasn't been there before. Realistically it could be something wrong with memPair(a customized predicate to check if a pair of values (a previous state in this case have been in the list). But tree proofs seemed to prove me wrong.

Comment: I am very confused about what you expect your `G1` and `G2` variables to be doing, and where you ever check to see if you have reached your ending point.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't used the simpler *representation* for this problem, and then your algorithm is far more complex that should be. As a consequence, there are problems I can spot at first glance - but I'm not sure that correcting them will make your program run.

- you don't *always* pass the same pattern to memPairs and recursive call of bucket, like `not(memPairs(X,Z,T)),bucket(4,Z,[4,Z|T],G1,G2).`
- `not(memPairs(Z,0,[T]))` should be `not(memPairs(Z,0,T))`

Also note the `:- dynamic bucket/4.` declaration is useless.

*edit* I suggest to rework your program in more Prolog-like style: use a *pair* for pairs: here a working sample

```
go(Actions) :- buckets([0-0], Actions).

buckets(Actions, Actions) :- Actions = [2-_|_] ; Actions = [_-2|_].
buckets([Buckets|SoFar], Steps) :-
    action(Buckets, Updated),
    \+ memberchk(Updated, SoFar),
    buckets([Updated,Buckets|SoFar], Steps).

action(B1-B2, C1-C2) :-
    B1 = 0, C1 =  3, C2 = B2 ; % fill Bucket 1
    B2 = 0, C2 =  4, C1 = B1 ; % fill Bucket 2
    B1 > 0, C1 =  0, C2 = B2 ; % empty Bucket 1
    B2 > 0, C2 =  0, C1 = B1 ; % empty Bucket 2
    B1 > 0, B2 < 4, T is min(B1, 4 - B2), C1 is B1 - T, C2 is B2 + T ; % pour Bucket 1 to 2
    B2 > 0, B1 < 3, T is min(B2, 3 - B1), C2 is B2 - T, C1 is B1 + T . % pour Bucket 2 to 1
```

*edit* There were useless parenthesis around disjunctions, now removed.